# (R): More digits in my tibble made by a converted vector

Tags: r

**Problem**

Let's say i construct a vector:

```
vec <- rnorm(100, 10, 10)
```

Now i convert this vector to a tibble:

```
vect <- tibble(vec)
```

```
vect
# A tibble: 100 × 1
     vec
   <dbl>
 1 16.1 
 2 17.3 
 3  5.17
 4 13.7 
 5  3.90
 6 13.2 
 7 16.6 
 8 12.1 
 9  8.80
10  8.68
# … with 90 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I now want more decimals for each value in each row, so i say:

```
vect$vec <- as.numeric(vect$vec)
```

and then i assume my column `vect$vec` is converted to a numeric column and now i must be able to use:

```
vect %>%
     mutate_if(as.numeric, round, digits = 10)
```

But it doesnt give me more decimals?

What do i do wrong?

Comment: The `vec` column is already numeric. The tibble will just round the numbers when printing.

Comment: Add a `%>% glimpse()` to the end of your code and you'll see the additional digits.

Comment: See `vignette("digits", package = "tibble")` and `vignette("numbers", package = "tibble")` for an explanation about how `tibble` prints numbers.

Comment: @Axeman, what do you suggest i should do then? Just convert the vector to a regular data.frame?

Comment: I tried the ```glimpe()``` function and i got two more digits out of it, when i test ran the mean and standard deviation:

```vect %>%
        glimpse() %>%
        summarize(
            meanVec = mean(vec),
            sdVec = sd(vec)
        )

# A tibble: 1 × 2
  meanVec sdVec
    <dbl> <dbl>
1    11.0  8.67```

But what if i want more digits than the 2 decimal it produces?

Comment: You may not have to do anything, depending on your goal. If you really need to see more digits, there's a few options. You can change the tibble options to show more numbers, using e.g. `options(pillar.sigfig = 10)`. Or specifically print the numbers in the format you want, with e.g. `format(vect$vec, digits = 10)`.